# cp: app/key.jks: No such file or directory on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jks

How to fix this error in Jenkins?

> [Pipeline] { (Setup Tools)
>
> [Pipeline] withCredentials
>
> Masking supported pattern matches of $KEYFILE
>
> [Pipeline] {
>
> [Pipeline] sh
>
> cp **** app/key.jks
>
> cp: app/key.jks: No such file or directory

**Pipeline Script**

```
 stage('Setup Tools') {
     withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'android_keystore', variable: 'KEYFILE')]) {
         sh "cp \$KEYFILE app/key.jks"
     }   
 }
```

JKS Credential added like this,

[image]

**Android Project**

**build.gradle**

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
```

**key.properties**

```
storePassword=123abc
keyPassword=123abc
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/don/Documents/key.jks
```

I followed this tutorial
[tutorial is here](https://medium.com/mindorks/automating-android-app-play-store-publishing-via-jenkins-a6c30dbc59dd)

Answer (score 0):

Do a ls, e.g.

```
 sh "ls"
```

//This will tell you if the folder is actually there, i always double check, something i could be in the wrong folder.

Then i think, it's becuase your not setting the env variable KEYFILE
To test this, try;

```
 sh "export KEYFILE=dave"
 sh "cp \$KEYFILE app/key.jks"
```

You should now get a error about unable to find dave.

Comment: thanks for supporting. I am very beginning for Jenkins. do you have idea what is the meaning of `app/`?

Comment: this is a linux command to copy a file , sh "cp \$KEYFILE app/key.jks"
What your saying is copy the $KEYFILE to the folder app, into a file call keys.jks. 

$KEYFILE is an environment variable, and if you don't set a value to it, it becomes "", nothing. so the cp command becomes sh "cp app/key.jks", when it should be sh "cp \nameOfFile app/key.jks"

Comment: I already set KEYFILE. you can see on my first image.  I set `android_keystore` in credential ```credentialsId: 'android_keystore', variable: 'KEYFILE'```

Comment: that just says there's a variable called KEYFILE, maybe it's not been set, try doing a echo $KEYFILE, this will help you confirm it.

Comment: result is ```echo
this is a ****```  echo "this is a ${KEYFILE}";

Comment: sh "cp \$KEYFILE app/key.jks" this mean copy file to app/key.jks right? Is it need to create directory?

Comment: ok, seems like the file variable is ok, now try changing the cp to just sh "cp \$KEYFILE key.jks", i think it maybe that the folder doesn't exists of that you don't have write access to it.

Comment: hmm do a sh ls -lrat, that will tell you the permission of the folder, if your lucky, you can do a chmod on the folder to say chmod -R 777 ./ , that will give everyone write,read,execute access. It will be ok for the time being.

so your jenkins file shoudl be like sh 'chmod -R 777 ./' sh 'cp $KEYFILE .\key.jks'